# Using unmanaged code, how can I find a type that has a given custom attribute assigned to it?

Tags: .net, reflection, unmanaged

I had thought I could enumerate the types using IMetaDataImport.EnumTypeDefs and
for each of the tokens returned, call IMetaDataImport.EnumCustomAttributes.

This works, in so much as I get an array of mdCustomAttribute tokens.  Using these tokens I can get a metadata token representing the Type of the returned custom attribute, by calling IMetaDataImport.GetCustomAttributeProps.

Comparing my results against ILDASM, I can see that this matches the "CustomAttribute Type" that ILDASM reports.  However, I cannot work out how to determine the "CustomAttributeName" that ILDASM reports.  This is what I really want!

While I would be interested in knowing how to get the CustomAttributeName, I would settle for an alternate approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Where in ILDASM do you see the term CustomAttributeName?

AFAIK, a custom attribute consists only of a type and a signature blob.

You're not talking about named arguments, are you?

Comment: In the main window, select a class from the treeview.  Then use "Show!" (Ctrl-M) to display the MetaInfo window.  
In here it lists the class, followed by the class's methods, followed by the custom attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this was a case of RTFM.  The attribute returned by `GetCustomAttributeProps` is not a typedef token, but a `mdMethodDef` or `mdMemberRef` token.
For mdMethodDef tokens, you use `IMetaDataImport.GetMethodProps` to find the typeDef token and for mdMemberRefs, it is a slightly longer path, but you start with `IMetaDataImport.GetMemberRefProps`.

The moral of the story is to pay attention to what sort of tokens these functions are returning!